# Set difference using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists - one involves only strings, the other involves instances including string property, i.e. `Name` - I want to carry the set difference operation on them.

```
var diff = request.MyStringList.Where(name => !request.Records.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(name));
```

For example,

- MyStringList contains `"jack", "aaron", "abraham"`
- Records' `Name`s are `"denny", "aaron", "abraham", "michael"`

I expect `diff` to include merely `"jack"`. What's my wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks sir, but what's the wrong of my expression/logic?

Comment: I tried your code and it works as expected. It returns only "jack". See https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpYfl8. Are some important details missed in the question?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev there may be, I'm glancing at again. _To err is human to forgive divine_, thanks, by the bye.

Answer (score 1):

try using Except

```
request.MyStringList.Except(request.Records.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Comment: Big warning, Except remove duplicates which might not be the desired behavior.

Comment: As to withdrawal of duplicates, a good example can be found here --> https://web.archive.org/web/20180306055918/http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/linq-expect-intersect-and-union-method-operator-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Except the other option is `Any` to test inclusion:

```
var diff = request.MyStringList.Where(name => !request.Records.Any(x => x.Name == name));
```

This will return duplicates that `Except` may (will) remove.

Alternatively a left join to stitch the items together.  In query syntax:

```
var diff = 
    from name in request.Records
    join r in request.Records on name equals r.Name into rtmp
    from r in rtmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r == null
    select name;
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but is there any wrong with my expression?